# get specific string after first occurance of string regex sublime text 2 find & replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

```
include_once($pathToRoot.'header.php');  
echo('</div>');
```

assume you have variations on the above code across hundreds of files, how do you match against the first occurrence of

```
</div>
```

after

```
header.php'
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the find field:
 `(?s)(header\.php'.+?)</div>`

In the replace (if you what to replace `</div>` with `</test>`):
`$1</test>`

Comment: Thank you the correct syntax for the s modifier was tripping me up

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that sublimetext2 but the regular expression would look like this:

```
/include_once\($pathToRoot.'header.php'\);(.*?)(<\/div>)/s
```

The first group would be the string between the include and the closing div and the second group would be the closing div itself.